# wildcard doesnot work for a new generated folder

Tags: linux, makefile, wildcard

I am trying to get a .tar.gz file name from a new generated folder (one step above). 
I tried to use wildcard , but with no luck,

In my makefile, I tried:

```
...
...
...
other parts
...

deb:
    python setup.py sdist   --- this step will generate a new folder called dist
    cd dist; ls -l          --- from here, I see the file is shown.
    echo $(wildcard dist/*.tar.gz)   (also tried dist/pylink*.tar.gz, dist/*.gz)  --fails!
```

I run it with make -f makefile deb.

I always got nothing from wildcard

But if I leave the folder generated by python, and rerun the file above, I can see the file name is written to the console. Anyone knows why? How should I do to get the file name? I need to use the filename and extend the filename to another one.

many many thanks!

Comment: The function should be spelled `wildcard`, not `wilcard`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my typo. already fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say so explicitly but I assume that, because you're using `$(wildcard ...)`, the lines you provide are part of a GNU make makefile rule.  It's best to provide a working example, when asking for help, not just a small bit of one.

The problem you're having is that make expands ALL variables and functions in ALL lines of the recipe, before it starts the first line of the recipe.  So even though the `$(wildcard ...)` doesn't appear until the third line of the recipe, it's expanded before the first line is run.  When the `$(wildcard ...)` function runs, those files don't yet exist so it expands to nothing.

Why don't you just use the shell globbing, since you're in a shell anyway?

```
python setup.py sdist
cd dist; ls -l
echo dist/*.tar.gz
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. So I tried in the makefile, $(shell find -name 'dist/pylink*.*') , still I got nothing.  Does this do what you mean by shell globbing. Sorry if the question is too naive.

Comment: No, I mean just what I wrote.  The capability of expanding special characters like `*`, `?`, and `[a-z]` etc. and matching them against filenames is called _globbing_, and the shell can do it by itself.  If you type `echo dist/*.tar.gz` then the shell will expand it for you.  You don't need make functions to do it.

Comment: As for `$(shell ...)`, that's a make function just like `$(wildcard ...)` and it's expanded at the same time and has the same issue: using a different make function won't help.  You have to stop using make functions altogether and rely on the shell to do the wildcard expansion.

Comment: For the second thought, about variable in makefile, if using = to set value for a variable, is the value set when the variable is used? if using := , the value is set when the variable is declared. Please point out my misunderstanding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a different question... there is no reference to variables in your original question.  When you assign a variable with `:=`, the variable value is expanded when the variable is assigned.  When you assign a variable with `=`, the variable value is expanded when the variable is used.

Comment: So this means if I define a variable then refer it later in the makefile, my problem can be solved. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: No.  As I've said above, ALL variables and ALL functions will be expanded before ANY commands in that recipe are started.  The variable/function is considered "used" at the time make decides it needs to run the `dep` target, _before_ it starts to invoke any of the commands in the `dep` recipe.  It doesn't matter what kind of variable it is.  You have exactly two choices: the one I mentioned in my answer (use the shell to look up the files), or break the statements into two different rules where one creates the files and the other uses `$(wildcard ...)` and have the second depend on the first.